# SSD on MacBook Pro - Strange capacity reporting in Finder

Tags: finder, ssd, trash

This is less of an issue and more of an 'enquiring minds would like to know' type question.

I have a 1TB SSD in my macBook pro. I've been utilising the space to sort through years of duplications of backups and photos, videos, Flacs and whatnot.

Anyhow, I got a warning of low space, checked and found it had only 4GB left. I deleted a few files, emptied the trash and it went up to 6GB. The trash icon showed empty. I then did the following to get more space:

1. I Copied a directory of some FLAC files to an external hard drive.
2. This directory was 20GB in size
3. After it had finished copying I deleted it from the SSD. The trash icon showed full.
4. I emptied the trash. The trash icon showed empty.
5. The capacity only rose to 16GB, rather than the 26GB expected.
6. I double checked the copied folder and it was 20GB.
7. I shut down the computer and restarted it.
8. After restart the capacity now showed 15.5GB
9. After about 20 seconds, the trash can icon changed from empty to full
10. I emptied the trash. Trash icon empty again
11. The capacity now showed 28GB

Unfortunately I didn't have my thinking head on and didn't check the trash to see what had materialised there before emptying it.

I'm guessing the OS (macOS Mojave 10.14.6) is still busy doing stuff in the background even though it shows it has finished, but trying to get my head around what it was doing conflicts with my existing understanding.

For example, when I deleted the directory of FLACs, that actually moves the directory to hidden folder ~/Trash so that should just be writing a directory entry and be virtually instantaneous.

When emptying the trash, it shows a progress bar of the remaining items to be deleted, so when that finishes, it should really be finished.

But it seems like something else must actually be happening under the hood  for the above behaviour to have occurred. Is finder lying when it shows it is emptying trash?

The disk format is APFS, and there is a 70GB partition for a beta/developer copy of Catalina, with the remainder used for the Mojave partition.

Comment: Have you tried opening Disk Utility to run First Aid on your drive. It sounds like you have an Invalid Block Size.

Comment: Thanks for the idea. I'm not sure what you mean by an 'invalid' block size (invalid in what way) but DU doesn't find any issues:
 Disk Size:                 1.0 TB (1000345825280 Bytes) (exactly 1953800440 512-Byte-Units)
Device Block Size:         4096 Bytes